# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13.05.2018' could not be parsed at index 2

Tags: java, json, websocket, gson, datetime-format

I have a `websocket` that receives requests from clients as `JSON` strings. One of the requests I receive contains a date. I am retrieving the date as a `String` but I am unable to change it to LocalDate. This is the `JSON` request I receive  `{"type":"dataRequest","startDate":"13.05.2018","endDate":"20.05.2018","interval":"01:01:01"}`

I am using `Google's GSON` to parse the `JSON`.

This is the `Java` code I am using to get the date as a `String` and to parse it as LocalDate.

```
private List<LocalDate> getStartEndDate(String message){

        List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList();
        JsonObject obj = parseJson(message);
        JsonPrimitive date = obj.getAsJsonPrimitive("startDate");
        String dateString = date.toString();
        DateTimeFormatter formater = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        dates.add(LocalDate.parse(dateString, formater));
        date = obj.getAsJsonPrimitive("endDate");
        dateString = date.getAsString();
        LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formater);
        dates.add(end);

        return dates;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] ? The format is correct and works properly with the date provided. `DateTimeFormatter formater = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.yyyy" ); System.out.println( LocalDate.parse( "13.05.2018", formater ) );` > `"2018-05-13"`

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with you code either. I am speculating whether your string may hold some funny char that we’re not aware of. You may want to log `Arrays.tostring(dateString.toCharArray())` for inspection before attempting to parse.

Answer (score 0):

## No problem

The kind of code you present here should be working. You have not presented enough information here to solve the problem.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/qmlafB).

```
String input = "20.05.2018" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.yyyy" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2018-05-20

### Debugging

When debugging such a problem, reduce the problem to its essential core. In this case, this means stripping away all the JSON business, to focus on getting the date-parsing to work properly by itself.

This also makes for a much better Question on Stack Overflow.

### ISO 8601

Best practice for exchanging date-time values as text is to always use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. See above for an example of this, YYYY-MM-DD format.